# Getting element using xpath and cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Trying to write a function in node.js that will get the element by xpath.

I have an xpath of the desired dom element like

```
xpath = '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/h1/span'
```

My DOM is loaded in **cheerio** via fs module (because I have this webpage stored locally):

```
var file = fs.readFileSync( "aaa.html" )
var inDom    = cheerio.load( file )
```

Then I am trying to iterate via each xpath part, get the element of the dom tree, check it's children if the name and element number matches, and if they do, store **rez** as this mathed element. Then I do continue to dig down with new xpath part. The code looks like this, but it fails to get what I want because just after I get the first mach and set **rez** as the matched element, in the next for loop cycle this new element seems not to have any children elements.

```
var rez = inDom('html');
var xpath = inXpath.split( "/" );
for( var i = iterateStart; i < xpath.length; i++ ) {
    var selector = xpath[ i ].split('[')[0];
    var matches = xpath[ i ].match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
    var child = 0;
    if( matches ) {
        child = matches[ 1 ];
    }

    for( var k = 0; k < rez.length; k++ ) {
        var found = false
        var curE = rez[ k ]

        for( var p = 0; p < curE.children.length; p++ ) {
            var curE_child = curE.children[ p ]

            if( curE_child.name = selector ) {
                if( child > 0 ) {
                    child--
                }
                else {
                    rez = curE_child
                    found = true
                    break
                }
            }               
        }
        if( found ) {
            break
        }
    }       
}
```

Can anybody help me with the code using mentioned node.js modules?

Answer (score 7):

It seems like you are doing way more work then you need to find the desired element. Can you post a sample html page?

Cheerio provides a higher-level api for finding elements that you should use.

```
var html = fs.readFileSync('aaa.html')
var $ = cheerio.load(html)
var selector = 'div' // some selector here which I can tune to the example html page
var parent = $(selector)
var childSelector = 'p' // some other selector 
var children = parent.find(childSelector)
```

Comment: I did implement your approach, and I stuck on getting, for example, third element, when the part of xpath is like '../div[3]/...'. I use the code pasted here http://pastebin.com/pzSYz6Zc The error is also pasted.

Comment: Without any sample html it is hard to give you suggestions. Please post an example html page

Comment: by webpage I mean aaa.html which you load via var file = fs.readFileSync( "aaa.html" )

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is xpath implementation:

```
npm install xpath
```

Sample:

```
var xml = "<book><title>Harry Potter</title></book>"
var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml)
var title = xpath.select("//title/text()", doc).toString()
console.log(title)
```

Source:
    https://www.npmjs.org/package/xpath

Comment: Unfortunately the DOM parser used in the example (xmldom) is very strict and does not work well with real HTML pages.

At the time I haven't found a forgiving DOM parser compatible with xpath, yet.